# what is an appropriate value for maxLag in node toobusy on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

We're evaluating using the toobusy module https://github.com/lloyd/node-toobusy on an app hosted on Heroku. I am not sure what an appropriate value for maxLag would be for Heroku environment. It seems like it would need a fair amount of playing around and tweaking to tune it? Anyone use this module in production and with what kind of setup (ie. dynos) and with what params?

Thanks!

Comment: As it stands this is sort of a polling question (there's no right or wrong answer for "anyone use this"). Perhaps you should put the "what is an appropriate value for maxLag" in the title, since that's more of a real question.

Comment: you're right. thanks, updated.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started running a small auto-complete RESTful service on heroku.
It serves lots of requests for each user (request is sent on each character the user types).
This service is running on two x1 dynos.

I need it to keep responding fast under load, so I'm also using [toobusy](https://github.com/lloyd/node-toobusy). At first I've set it to max lag of 10ms but that was an ambitious goal - it denied many requests when I ran a load test.

After some tweaking - I've ended up with **max lag of 40ms**. It gave me a good balance between the load (amount of requests service needs to handle) and the desired response time (before denying requests).
I'm monitoring my app for denied requests due to load, so I'm able to add more dynos when needed.

I believe you'll have to play with this value and run load tests to get to the right number as it's very specific to the hardware (in your case Heroku) and what your app is doing for each request.